# How to create a symlink within browserFS

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, symlink, fs

I'm trying to create a symlink inside of BrowserFS.

I can confirm that BrowserFS can read sym links just fine... (I tested by making a zip file and loading it in, and doing `fs.readFile` and all is A-OK)

However, when I try to create a sym link via `fs.symlink`, I get an Error, I assume this is meaning it is not supported.

Can any of the folks out there that may use browserFS know how to propertly create, or any workarounds for creating symlinks?

One idea is to create the contents of a symlink and set file modes, but I had a hard time finding the exact way to do that. Any help appreciated!

I've included a codesandbox in case anyone is interested! https://codesandbox.io/s/43wroyjy9w

Comment: What was required for you to be able to manually create a sym link?

Comment: @Ouroborus for my test I created a zip file on my real file system, and downloaded it with `fetch` api and mounted it as a zip file system into browserfs. That proved that I could read a symlink that I created on my real computer's filesystem.

Comment: But you didn't actually create a sym link? You just read a regular file?

Comment: they both worked!

Comment: but that is just reading symlinks from the zip. the goal is to create a symlink inside of browserfs